# Merge 2 bitmaps in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, merge, bitmap

I have a few bitmaps and need to merge them, for example something like this:

I have these 2 pics

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

and need this:

[image: pic 3]

I know there are lots of ways but I need fastest way for combining them because in each iteration we need to combine lots of images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already? Stack isn´t the place to ask for ready to copy solutions. You have to provide somw own affords and show where you´re stuck. Having said this your question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Have you tried this?

```
public static Bitmap CombineBitmap(string[] files)
    {


        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(files[0]);

        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);
        g.Clear(SystemColors.AppWorkspace);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
             img = new Bitmap(file);

            img.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
            g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));


        }
return img3;
}
```

files is an array of files name.